# How does multiple "ON" in a JOIN statement works

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently reading a query that I don't usually see in some other queries when joining tables.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM table_1 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_2 
    INNER JOIN table_3 
        ON table_2.some_id = table_3.some_id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_4 
        ON table_3.some_id = table_4.some_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_5 
        ON table_4.some_id = table_5.some_id 
        ON table_1.some_id = table_4.some_id
```

Please don't mind how those tables being joined. I just want to know how did that query works? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting, didn't even know you could do that. Would have used and myself.

Comment: Could be a bug, would multiple `ON` clauses be synonymous for `AND` or `OR`?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I just created [a very simple example in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d8815/1) and it showed up as a syntax error, as I would expect.

Comment: @IMSoP - Actually I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2005. It's really weird that query possibly works. Which I agree to your comment.

Comment: @IMSoP Here's an example that captures the essence of the question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0e127/3

Comment: It seems that the fact you're using `outer join` as the first join matters: [this version with all `inner join`s](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0e127/7) is invalid...

Comment: The plot thickens, however: [PostgreSQL will evaluate it even with `inner joins`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0e127/1).

Comment: @IMSoP . . . In that case, it *must* be standard SQL.  After all, what other than the standard would SQL Server, MySQL, and Postgres all agree on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the SQL Server documentation captures what is happening better than MySQL.  ([Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) is the documentation.)

This is a parsing issue, as Laurence has observed.  You can understand what is by looking at the syntax diagram for the `from` statement.  There is a recursive reference that most people never think about (including me).  A joined table has the following syntax:

```
<joined_table> ::= 
{
    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition> 
    | <table_source> CROSS JOIN <table_source> 
    | left_table_source { CROSS | OUTER } APPLY right_table_source 
    | [ ( ] <joined_table> [ ) ] 
}
```

The key here is the first piece, `<table_source> <join_type> <table_source>`.  Well, guess what, a `table_source` can be a `joined_table` (as well as a bunch of other things).  This means that the syntax:

```
A join B join C ON <condition1> ON <condition2>
```

Fits the grammar above and is interpreted as:

```
A join (B join C on <condition1>) ON <condition2>
```

That is, the expression `B join C on <condition1>` is treated as a "table_source".

My guess is that if both SQL Server and MySQL do it this way, then it is probably part of the standard.  However, the standard is a bit harder to understand than SQL Server's syntax diagrams.

Comment: The [PostgreSQL manual includes this line](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM): "Joins of all types can be chained together or nested: either or both T1 and T2 can be joined tables. Parentheses can be used around JOIN clauses to control the join order. In the absence of parentheses, JOIN clauses nest left-to-right." The key being that the parentheses are optional, so the syntax recurses even without them.

Comment: This doesn't quite explain why MySQL rejects it if they are all `INNER JOIN`s though. I suspect it is because MySQL accepts an `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` (treating it as a `CROSS JOIN` by the looks of [this experiment](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/a6fbd/1)). Thus the first `INNER JOIN` gets used that way, rather than as joining to a nested set of joins, and the last `ON` is left orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is down to the way right outer join is evaluated:

```
Select
  * 
from 
  a
    right outer join 
  b
    inner join
  c 
    on b.id = c.id 
    on a.id = b.id;
```

is evaluated as

```
Select
  * 
from 
  a
    right outer join (
  b
    inner join
  c 
    on b.id = c.id 
  )
    on a.id = b.id;
```

Mixing left and right outer join is a path to madness.

The OP's query seems to be driven by a desire to exclude parenthesis, or derived tables. It is equivalent to:

```
Select
    a.id ida,
    b.id idb,
    c.id idc,
    d.id idd,
    e.id ide
From
    D
        left outer join
    A
        on d.id = a.id
        left outer join
    E
        on d.id = e.id
        left outer join (
    B
        inner join
    C
        on b.id = c.id
    ) 
        on d.id = b.id;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/907772/6)</kbd>**

Comment: The last sentence of this answer, though probably a good point, is a non-sequitur, since the example you show doesn't mix left and right outer joins.

Comment: @IMSoP The OPs question does.

Comment: Yes, but it's not relevant to the problem at hand, so would be better suited to a separate comment, or labelled as an aside. The way it's written here, it makes it sound like not mixing them would make the problem go away, which is clearly false.

Comment: @IMSoP I see two problems here, one is why does the query not produce a syntax error, the second is how to rewrite it to be sane. I agree the comment isn't relevant to the first problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example and explanation @Laurence. :)